# How to insert select tag drop down values as text snippet at a particular cursor position inside the text area tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a list of predefined text snippet that I want to insert into the text area at the current cursor position, whenever user selects one snippet from the drop down list.

I have tried to do implement it like the following but it didn't work. 
I am getting this error:

> add_home:228 Uncaught TypeError: field.setSelectionRange is not a function

Please help me solve this. Thank you.

```js
function insertAtCursor(text, areaId) {
  var field = document.getElementById(areaId);

  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();

    if (!range || range.parentElement() != field) {
      field.focus();
      range = field.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(false);
    }
    range.text = text;
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
  } else {
    field.focus();
    var val = field.value;
    var selStart = field.selectionStart;
    var caretPos = selStart + text.length;
    field.value = val.slice(0, selStart) + text + val.slice(field.selectionEnd);
    field.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Home</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <form method="post" id="addHomeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
              <select name="snippetForseoTitle" id="snippetForseoTitle" class="form-control" unselectable="on" onchange="insertAtCursor(this.value, 'snippetForseoTitle'); return false">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Insert Snippet</option>
                <option value="%%site_title%%">Site Title</option>
                <option value="%%seperator%%">Seperator</option>
                <option value="%%primary_category%%">Primary Category</option>
                <option value="%%primary_store%%">Primary Store</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="seoTitle">SEO Title</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="seoTitle" id="seoTitle" placeholder="SEO Title"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
              <select name="snippetForseoMetaDesc" id="snippetForseoMetaDesc" class="form-control">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Insert Snippet</option>
                <option value="%%site_title%%">Site Title</option>
                <option value="%%seperator%%">Seperator</option>
                <option value="%%primary_category%%">Primary Category</option>
                <option value="%%primary_store%%">Primary Store</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="seoMetaDesc">SEO Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="seoMetaDesc" id="seoMetaDesc" placeholder="SEO Meta Description"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
            <label for="seoKeyPhrase">SEO Keyphrase</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="seoKeyPhrase" id="seoKeyPhrase" placeholder="SEO Keyphrase">
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <div class="box-footer text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're passing the `select`'s ID, not the `texarea`'s ID

Comment: `insertAtCursor(this.value, 'snippetForseoTitle');` should be `insertAtCursor(this.value, 'seoTitle');`

Comment: It worked! Silly mistake. Thank you sir for helping me out! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sir, how can I make the inserted snippet distinguishable from normal texts inside the text  area ..? how can I change the styles of the selected snippet  texts ?

Comment: `<Textarea>` is just that text - you'll want a rich text editor third party control (better to get one already built that try to recreate it)

Comment: Sir I could not able to insert consecutive  same  snippet  from the drop down list. I mean if  I  try  to insert the site_title snippet one time first time it works then if I want to insert the same snippet again it wont work. How to fix that sir?

Answer (score 1):

I was passing wrong ids that is why it was not working! I have implemented it properly now and it is working smoothly.

```js
function insertAtCursor(text, areaId) {
  var field = document.getElementById(areaId);

  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();

    if (!range || range.parentElement() != field) {
      field.focus();
      range = field.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(false);
    }
    range.text = text;
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
  } else {
    field.focus();
    var val = field.value;
    var selStart = field.selectionStart;
    var caretPos = selStart + text.length;
    field.value = val.slice(0, selStart) + text + val.slice(field.selectionEnd);
    field.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Home</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <form method="post" id="addHomeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
              <select name="snippetForseoTitle" id="snippetForseoTitle" class="form-control" unselectable="on" onchange="insertAtCursor(this.value, 'seoTitle'); return false">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Insert Snippet</option>
                <option value="%%site_title%%">Site Title</option>
                <option value="%%seperator%%">Seperator</option>
                <option value="%%primary_category%%">Primary Category</option>
                <option value="%%primary_store%%">Primary Store</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="seoTitle">SEO Title</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="seoTitle" id="seoTitle" placeholder="SEO Title"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
              <select name="snippetForseoMetaDesc" id="snippetForseoMetaDesc" class="form-control" unselectable="on" onchange="insertAtCursor(this.value, 'seoMetaDesc'); return false">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Insert Snippet</option>
                <option value="%%site_title%%">Site Title</option>
                <option value="%%seperator%%">Seperator</option>
                <option value="%%primary_category%%">Primary Category</option>
                <option value="%%primary_store%%">Primary Store</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="seoMetaDesc">SEO Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="seoMetaDesc" id="seoMetaDesc" placeholder="SEO Meta Description"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
            <label for="seoKeyPhrase">SEO Keyphrase</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="seoKeyPhrase" id="seoKeyPhrase" placeholder="SEO Keyphrase">
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
          </fieldset>

          <div class="box-footer text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```